# Python binance - get futures position information

Tags: python, binance-api-client, python-binance

I would like to retrieve future position histroy from the Binance API, just like it is on the dashboard.

I need this data to then later display on a spreadsheet.

[image: position history]

Thank you.

I've tried to play with the client.futures_account_trades().

client.futures_position_information() retrieves only currently active position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 3 months of research I found that there’s no endpoint to return all those fields together, user needs to program locally.

I would suggest you to explore the available endpoints at the Futures API document first, namely:
https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#account-trade-list-user_data

or if using Websocket Stream:
https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#event-balance-and-position-update

And test their behavior with your Futures Testnet Account, which can be created at:
https://testnet.binancefuture.com/en/futures/ADAUSDT
After created, you can obtain the API Key/ API secret key in the “API key” tab below.